# Alias multiple folders into one

Tags: finder, automator, folders, alias, folder-action

Here's the thing:
I'm organizing my document (for example to organize papers). I divide them into subsections, (ex: astrophysics & quantum physics) and all those sections have a "Read", "Reading" and "To Read" folders. Could I alias all the files contained in the folder efficiently to have a folder where all papers (or at least their aliases) are present (no matter if they were in astrophysics or quantum physics). I wouldn't mind using automator folder actions if shown how...

Example Folder Structure:

```
All Read:
    Nice paper I read about astrophysics.alias
    Nice paper I read about Quantum Physics.alias
All Reading:
    Nice paper I am reading about astrophysics.alias
    Nice paper I am reading about Quantum Physics.alias
All To Read:
    Nice paper I should read about astrophysics.alias
    Nice paper I should read about Quantum Physics.alias
Astrophysics:
    Read:
        Nice paper I read about astrophysics.pdf
    Reading:
        Nice paper I am reading about astrophysics.pdf
    To Read:
        Nice paper I should read about astrophysics.pdf
Quantum Physics:
    Read:
        Nice paper I read about Quantum Physics.pdf
    Reading:
        Nice paper I am reading about Quantum Physics.pdf
    To Read:
        Nice paper I should read about Quantum Physics.pdf
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough clarity for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. Can you please edit your question (there's an _edit_ link below it) to clarify what you're trying to do? For example, it's not clear what your current state is, so trying to help you get to the folder structure you want is going to be difficult without that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like find .. -name "*.pdf" -exec ln -s {} basename